# How to read data from csv file

Tags: tcl

I am having a csv file Book1.csv. I want to read data so as to use this in my script. I am not able to read in row-column format. Suppose i am having a column named "7-slot" and having data "1 2 3 4 5" and so on. Dont know how to read. Searched from Google and stackoverflow but didnt get.

```
package require csv
package require struct::matrix

# Load the file into a matrix
struct::matrix data
set f [open Book1.csv]
csv::read2matrix $f data , auto
close $f
```

This code i have taken from stackoverflow onlt. I am new to TCL so learning these things

Comment: What's missing, is the actual question. "I'm not able to read ..." is not a question.  The code appears to be correct so either provide (way) more details or try making your code work with a simplistic CSV file (say, 3x3) created by hand and when it works try understanding why it doesn't for your real-life case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, I think what's missing is adding columns to your matrix before reading into it.

This snippet:

```
package require csv
package require struct::matrix

struct::matrix m
m add columns 3
set f [open foo.csv]
csv::read2matrix $f m ,
close $f
puts [m serialize]
```

produces for `foo.csv` containing

```
1,2,3
"aaa","bbb","ccc"
```

this printout:

```
2 3 {{1 2 3} {aaa bbb ccc}}
```

Which I parse as "a matrix of 2 rows and 3 columns and then the list of lists which represents rows and column values for each.

Comment: The auto option on the read2matrix command should make the matrix expand as needed. I think something else is going on here but I can't see what.